# Rails plug and play validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Here is my example

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with EmailValidator
end

class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record != someregex
      record.errors.add(:email, 'invalid email')
    end
  end
end
```

Now I can use this `EmailValidator` for any model. But my requirement is to validate its uniqueness and presence also for that particular model.

If I can achieve this I can use this `EmailValidator` for any model email validation with functionalities unique, presence.

Then I can achieve more reusable Validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by rewriting your validator to be `EachValidator`:

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if attribute !~ someregex
      record.errors.add attribute, (options[:message] || 'invalid email')
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your model:

```
validates :email, email: true, uniqueness: true, presence: true
```

Hope that helps.